# Huffman encoding - header & EOF

Tags: algorithm, encoding, header, eof, huffman-code

I am currently working on implementing a program based on the huffman algorithm in Java, and I am at the stage where I need to output the encoded content to a file. I am a bit confused about how to implement the header and eof needed for decoding. For my header at the moment I have all the unique values that occur from the input file and their frequency, but on some articles I have seen people do it with 0 or 1 represents the nodes and then the frequency (which I am a bit puzzled by as it doesn't say what the symbol is).

Also, for the EOF as I understand it I encode it like the symbols so it gets read and decoded, however I am not sure what value I can use for it that will definitely not come up? I know it needs to a weight of 1 but was unsure how to make sure it won't actually be in the file.

Comment: What articles? Could you provide some links?

Comment: The main two I was looking at were http://michael.dipperstein.com/huffman/ and http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/poop/huff/info/ after thinking about the header I can see why they are doing it now I think (construct a tree using the header then you get frequencies by reading the content of file? At the moment mine has symbols and frequencies in header which is wrong) It's just the pseudo-eof code I'm confused by as I'm not sure what to use for it as isn't a possible the code could be a symbol already in the tree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had to do this once for an assignment and this is the approach we used.

Encoding the header was done by using 0 and 1 to encode the structure of the tree (rather than the frequencies). A "0" denoted moving along the tree, a "1" denoted we were at a leaf node. This resulted in a sort of pre-order traversal of the tree encoding it uniquely.

For example, a tree like (((a b) c) (d e)) would be encoded as "0001`a`1`b`1`c`01`d`1`e`", where a,b,c,d,e are their ASCII forms.

Here's the tree in a graphical form:

```
     / \
   /\   /\
 /\  c d  e
a  b
```

For the EOF we used the last 3 bits in the file to specify how many of the last two bytes needed to be read. Once we read the last byte (so we were working on the second last byte) we checked the last 3 bits: They encoded how many more bits to read, minus 6. So `110101xxxxxxx000` meant "read `110101` (6 bits) and discard everything else". `1101011xxxxxx001` meant "read `1101011` (7 bits) and discard the rest", etc.

Doing it this way meant we didn't have to have a special value denoting the EOF and we could still read the file a byte at a time (although we actually needed to read one byte ahead of where we were working).

(For the EOF I haven't read your articles, so I don't know if our idea works with your approach.)

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand the header better but could you clarify the example a bit more? I am not sure I am reading the tree correctly, is it: Root Node, then a Super Node with another Super Node inside with the A + B leaves and a C leave Node (outside of the inside Super Node holding A + B), then another Super Node with the D and E leaves? If so, does "0001a1b1c" say that after you read the two leaves you just assume after you have that the next leave is outside?

Comment: I've added a bit of a more intuitive representation of the tree, so I hope that helps. You know where you're placing leaves, and it's always into a left-most position, so the next left-most position is where the next 'bit' operates. 000 -> go down left branch, 1 -> place a in current position and move to next leftmost non-leaf node, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Huffman encoding specifies how to create the Huffman tree from some sequence of characters and then how to encode that into a sequence of bits.

It doesn't specify how should you encode the tree or how to figure out exactly how many bits to read. The exact count of bits is a problem, because you can save only whole bytes into a file. And so you need some way to figure out exactly at which bit to end.

For encoding the tree, there are several options. One of them is recording the count for each character and letting the decoder reconstruct the tree from that. Other option is to directly encode the tree somehow, for example using the 0-1 approach mange (and I assume the articles you mentioned) describes.

Then there is [adaptive Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Huffman_coding) which doesn't require the tree at all, but is more complicated.

For deciding when to end, you could write the total count of characters into the file and use that to decide when to stop. Or you could get this count for free if you encoded the tree using character counts.

Another option is to use an EOF character. This is a character that is in your Huffman tree, but doesn't encode any normal value. You could imagine it as a 257th value, assuming you are encoding bytes. (You *could* use some normal value, like the zero byte, for the EOF token, but that would require you to be absolutely sure it won't be present in the input file.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply I think I can do the EOF now but thanks for the total count suggestion (can't believe I didn't think of it!) in case it doesn't.

Comment: @svick I get that the character has to have a value of >256 but if it's not an ASCII character, how would I put it into the file?

Comment: @C_B The same way as ay other character: by encoding its position in the tree.