# Huffman Coding - Pseudo EOF

Tags: c++, eof, huffman-code

I have coded the huffman tree without problems but now I look to add the Pseudo EOF in the file and tree so I know when to stop reading from the file.

I fully grasp the concept of the Pseudo EOF. I also understand that there are no characters with an ASCII value of > 255.

What I don't fully understand is the adding of that character to the input file. If it has to be a non-ASCII character (because they can be in the file) then what character am I supposed to add to indicate EOF?

Comment: I´ve no idea wht you´re talking about, and there is no ASCII char >256.

Comment: Yes I get that. I'm just not sure what to use as an EOF character as the ASCII characters can all be present in the file.

Comment: I still don´t know what you´re talking about. Is the problem that you don´t know the size of a file?

Comment: I get your question and sadly you have to work around this; no byte is long enough. One idea we used for our students is a class that writes the number of bits to read and then the bits plus padding to a multiple of eight. After that, you read bytes.

Comment: The input file can be any text file. All I'm trying to do is to add a character to symbolize EOF. The problem with that is that I am unsure what character to add as all ASCII characters could be present. The EOF part of the answer by @svick to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198801/huffman-encoding-header-eof) is what I'm after.

Comment: @tgmath Aha, that makes sense. I was thinking, the implementation of that seemed impossible. Perhaps make your comment the answer so we can get closure to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you do really understand what a "pseudo EOF" is all about.

First, as per the comments, there is no ASCII char greater than 256. Nor is one needed.

What you are being asked to do is to simulate this in code. Say you have a function that reads a character:

```
int getchar(fhandle);
```

This function will return values from 0 to 255 to represent ASCII characters. It can also return a special value such as -1 to indicate end of file. This special value is the "pseudo EOF".

This character is not in the file. It is returned by the function when there are no more characters in the file.

Comment: I see what you're doing, but we are instructed to add a leaf node with a frequency of 1 and the value of n+1 with n being the max value of an ASCII character (255). So how can I add that to the tree then, thanks for your response.

Comment: Why is there an issue in adding a value of n+1 in a Huffman tree? There's no reason the tree can't include values that are >= 256.

Comment: I agree. The instructions seem clear. Just make sure the data item holding the value is an int, not a char.

Comment: @rcgldr I see, I have a tree of chars and have created a char that equals 256 for the pseudo eof. Thanks for clearing that up, all works as it should now.